# How to sort Task based on Project’s property

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore, I was tasked with creating a field called 'publish date' at the project level and using that field to sort, filter, and display on tasks. I created a taxonomy and a field using a schema, but I couldn't accomplish it. Is there any way I can utilize a project property to sort and filter tasks?

I created a taxonomy and a properly using a schema on M.project.block, and tried to use it to sort tasks. But it is not available on task level.